# Procedure to run Lancet code by Stuart Halloway in programming clojure

Tags: clojure

In Stuart Halloway's book "[Programming Clojure](http://pragprog.com/book/shcloj/programming-clojure)" he talks about the development of "Lancet". How can we run this Lancet if we don't have the complete code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple google search finds: https://github.com/stuarthalloway/lancet

But I still think you're better off with [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen).

Also, it's probably worth pointing out that lancet has changed since the publication of the book, so you might want to look at an [older version](https://github.com/stuarthalloway/lancet/commits/master/lancet.clj).

And, unsurprisingly, you can download the code from the book from the [pragmatic programmers website](http://pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/source_code).